# Yubikey Openssh sign certificate integration

Tags: yubico, yubikey

Actually, I use my YUBIKEY for ssh authentication with PKCS11 PIV tool.

I follow this step :
https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/SSH_user_certificates.html

at the end of this developer Guide there is this line :

```
ssh-add -L > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-keygen -s ~/.ssh/ca -I identity -n "${LOGNAME}" ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

`id_rsa-cert.pub` is generate and all work fine if I  try to authenticate one my openssh server.

But I want to store this id_rsa-cert.pub (public id sign by my CA), in my yubikey ...

I don't know how to do that ...

Any idea ?

(My CA is on my server, I have a copy on my client just for the POC)

---

Update : 16/11/2021

It's because yubikey use x509 certificats, and ssh RSA certificats ... just not compatible ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already on your yubikey. Step 2 imported the public and the private key to it.